# How can I specify Eclipse Preferences using plugin_customization.ini?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am writing Eclipse Plugin to support custom programming language. I want to specify some default preferences (like default Perspective id, showing line numbers, autosave resources before launch) using `plugin_customization.ini`.

The problem is that there are two other `plugin_customization.ini` files for plugins in folders `org.eclipse.epp.package.standard_2.0.2.20140224-0000` and `org.eclipse.platform_4.3.2.v20140221-1700` (both stored in `eclipse/plugins`) in Eclipse standard package and their `plugin_customization.ini` files somehow seem to have higher priority then my file (`org.eclipse.epp.package.standard_2.0.2.20140224-0000`comes first).

How can I change this order to make my plugin's `plugin_customization.ini` primary preferences file? Is there any other way to define preferences I mentioned?

Answer (score 6):

The plugin_customization.ini for the product that Eclipse is asked to run (via the -product entry in the eclipse.ini) is the one that is used. Eclipse packages often contain more than one product which is why you see multiple files.

You can specify the file to use by specifying the `-pluginCustomization` option on the command line or in the eclipse.ini

```
-pluginCustomization
/path-to-file/plugin_customization.ini
```

It is also possible to use a plugin that uses the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point to declare a new product and build a customized Eclipse RCP that runs this product - that is what the org.eclipse.epp.package.standard plugin is doing.

Comment: Is there any way to do this (change eclipse.ini) automatically using my Plugin? I want to install this Plugin on standart Eclipse and after installation (rebooting IDE) have Preferences initialized with values I specified in plugin_customization.ini. How can I avoid manual editing of eclipse.ini?

Comment: And speaking of `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` - I used that extension in my Plugin, tied one property with plugin_customization.ini but my Plugin seems not to be primary one, the `org.eclipse.epp.package.standard` still is and it's preferences get initialized on startup.

Comment: Defining a product is not enough, it must be the product that Eclipse is actually starting. You could try starting eclipse with `-product your-product-id`

Comment: So I can't just install plugin so that it's preferences would somehow override default ones after reloading Eclipse? And  starting Eclipse with `-product your-product-id` also can't be specified in Plugin, I suppose?

Comment: @user3655077 No, remember that the Eclipse may have thousands of plugins installed, all of them may think they are the most important plugin. So if you want to make sure your plugin takes precedence, you must handle that manually.

Comment: If you want your plugin to be in control you will have to do a custom RCP with your plugin as the product.